# Reduce repeated pivoting to a single pivot

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Using `tidyr` >= 1.0.0, one can use `tidy` selection in the `cols` argument as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("DL_TM"),
               names_to = "TM",values_to = "DM_TM") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("DL_CD"),
               names_to = "CD",values_to = "DL_CD") %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  select(-TM,-CD)
```

**However, the above will quickly get cumbersome(repetitive) with many columns, how can one reduce this to single `pivot`ing?!** I have imagined something conceptual like 
`pivot_longer(cols=starts_with("DL_TM | DL_CD")....)` which will obviously not work because `tidy` selection only works for a single pattern(as far as I know).

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(DL_TM1 = c(16L, 18L, 53L, 59L, 29L, 3L), DL_CD1 = c("AK", 
"RB", "RA", "AJ", "RA", "RS"), DL_TM2 = c(5L, 4L, 8L, NA, 1L, 
NA), DL_CD2 = c("CN", "AJ", "RB", NA, "AJ", NA), DL_TM3 = c(NA, 
NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), DL_CD3 = c(NA, NA, "AJ", NA, NA, NA), DL_TM4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DL_CD4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DL_TM5 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DL_CD5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), DEP_DELAY_TM = c(21L, 
22L, 63L, 59L, 30L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

**Expected Output**:
Same as the above but with single `pivot`ing.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck That actually does the trick. I didn't know `names_pattern` could do the trick.

Comment: Have moved comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the response to the comment that this was moved from the code in the question does not actually produce the desired result and what was wanted was the result that this produces:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-DEP_DELAY_TM, names_to = c(".value", "X"), 
    names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d)") %>%
  select(-X) %>%
  drop_na
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   DEP_DELAY_TM DL_TM DL_CD
          <int> <int> <chr>
 1           21    16 AK   
 2           21     5 CN   
 3           22    18 RB   
 4           22     4 AJ   
 5           63    53 RA   
 6           63     8 RB   
 7           63     2 AJ   
 8           59    59 AJ   
 9           30    29 RA   
10           30     1 AJ   
11            3     3 RS
```

### Base R

We can alternately do this using base R's `reshape`.  First split the column names (except the last column) by the non-digit parts giving the `varying` list and then reshape `df` to long form using that and finally run `na.omit` to remove the rows with NAs.

```
nms1 <- head(names(df), -1)
varying <- split(nms1, gsub("\\d", "", nms1))
na.omit(reshape(df, dir = "long", varying = varying, v.names = names(varying)))
```

giving:

```
    DEP_DELAY_TM time DL_CD DL_TM id
1.1           21    1    AK    16  1
2.1           22    1    RB    18  2
3.1           63    1    RA    53  3
4.1           59    1    AJ    59  4
5.1           30    1    RA    29  5
6.1            3    1    RS     3  6
1.2           21    2    CN     5  1
2.2           22    2    AJ     4  2
3.2           63    2    RB     8  3
5.2           30    2    AJ     1  5
3.3           63    3    AJ     2  3
```

Answer (score 3):

We can extract the column groupings ("TM" and "CD" in this case), `map` over each column group to apply `pivot_longer` to that group, and then `full_join` the resulting list elements. Let me know if this covers your real-world use case.

```
suffixes = unique(gsub(".*_(.{2})[0-9]*", "\\1", names(df)))

df.long = suffixes %>% 
  map(~ df %>% 
         mutate(id=1:n()) %>%  # Ensure unique identification of each original data row
         select(id, DEP_DELAY_TM, starts_with(paste0("DL_",.x))) %>%
         pivot_longer(cols=-c(DEP_DELAY_TM, id),
                      names_to=.x,
                      values_to=paste0(.x,"_value")) %>% 
         na.omit() %>% 
         select(-matches(paste0("^",.x,"$")))
  ) %>% 
  reduce(full_join) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

> ```
>    DEP_DELAY_TM TM_value CD_value
> 1            21       16       AK
> 2            21       16       CN
> 3            21        5       AK
> 4            21        5       CN
> 5            22       18       RB
> 6            22       18       AJ
> 7            22        4       RB
> 8            22        4       AJ
> 9            63       53       RA
> 10           63       53       RB
> 11           63       53       AJ
> 12           63        8       RA
> 13           63        8       RB
> 14           63        8       AJ
> 15           63        2       RA
> 16           63        2       RB
> 17           63        2       AJ
> 18           59       59       AJ
> 19           30       29       RA
> 20           30       29       AJ
> 21           30        1       RA
> 22           30        1       AJ
> 23            3        3       RS
> ```